# Defining Any.proto in the .proto files

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I am trying to define my own messages representing python classes that I want to serialize. However, I need to import any.proto or timestamp.proto in my .proto files to represent certain messages

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "/google/protobuf/any.proto";

message Test {
   google.protobuf.Any var1 = 1;
}
```

However, seems like the protobuf installation does not come with any .proto files. I am using python 3.5 and have protobuf 3.5.2 installed.  I tried to look under my site-packages i.e `site-packages/google/protobuf/` and there were no *.proto files but just found compiled files like `ant_pb2.py` and `timestamp_pb2.py`. I am following docs here to import `any.proto` - https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any